how to map Navigation property same file to parent
Source:
internal class ProductSupplierReportMiddle
{
    public ProductSupplierReport ProductSupplierReport { get; set; }

    public BaseEndProductProduceOrder EndProductProduceOrder { get; set; }
}

Destination:
public class ProductSupplierReportDto
{
    public Guid UUID{ get; set; }
    public string BillCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime BillDate { get; set; }

    public string SourceOrderCode{ get; set; }
}

The current approach I can think
CreateMap<ProductSupplierReportMiddle, ProductSupplierReportDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.UUID, opts => opts.MapFrom(e => e.ProductSupplierReport.UUID))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.BillCode, opts => opts.MapFrom(e => e.ProductSupplierReport.BillCode))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.BillDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(e => e.ProductSupplierReport.BillDate))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.SourceOrderCode, opts => opts.MapFrom(e => e.EndProductProduceOrder.BillCode))

can i Omit it the ProductSupplierReport map,because i have many same file

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers
